# ¿Cómo consigo la URL de la canción?

Tags: json, api, url, go, youtube

¡Hola! Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Golang, ya tengo hecha la mayor parte y solo me falta algo que ciertamente me está costando.
Quiero poder extraer las URLs de audio de YouTube Music, ya tengo he investigado y tratado de solucionarlo pero no lo logro.

Si accedo a https://music.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/player usando el método **POST**
obtengo mucha información útil, esto pasando lo siguiente como cuerpo de la solicitud:

```json
{
      "context":{
        "client": {
            "clientName": "WEB_REMIX", 
            "clientVersion": "1.20230306.01.00",
            "hl": "es-419"
        }
    },
    "videoId": "<Aquí el id de la canción>"
}
```

La información que obtengo devuelve campos muy interesantes incluyendo uno llamado **streamingData,** el cual contiene **microformats,** y en ese campo obtengo información muy relevante para la solicitud, pero aún no sé cómo realizarla. dejaré al final un ejemplo de la información que estoy mencionando.

La cosa es que allí, en el campo signatureCipher, está mucha información de la URL, esto lo he comprobado comparando la información con la URL que solicita YouTube Music al pedir la canción, pero aún así faltan algunos datos según mis análisis.

**Falta:**
*range*: Indica que rango de la canción se quiere, esto es para trocearla y va desde 0 hasta el valor indicado en contenLength, ejemplo range=0-15000 devolverá desde el byte 0 al 15000.

*sig*: No sé a que se refiera pero suele ser una cadena algo larga.
*pot*: Tampoco sé a que se refiera e igual suele ser algo largo.

La solicitud siempre se niega si se hace de una IP diferente, por lo que si van a probar recuerden que deben solicitar la pista desde la misma IP que solicitó el contenido en **/player,** o por lo menos colocarla en el campo **IP** de la solicitud

Para obtener la URL de la canción en si y compararla con está entré a YouTube Music, le di a la tecla F12 o opciones de desarrolladores y allí le di a red, una vez allí, filtré la URL que contenga **playback** y la primera que salga es la que se debe de analizar ya que las demás son trocitos.
Si quieren obtener la canción completa deben de buscar el tamaño para indicarlo en el range o usar un número absurdo como 99999999.
Estoy usando ***[POSTMAN](https://www.postman.com/)*** para tener una vista más ordenada de las partes de la solicitud.

Recuerdo que el problema consiste en cómo obtener la URL valida para poder solicitar la canción. ¡Agradezco su ayuda!

Respuesa al hacer la solicitud a https://music.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/player
está filtrada de la siguiente forma y recuerden arriba está el como accederla.

```js
streamingData.adaptiveFormats[]
```

```json
 {
                "itag": 137,
                "mimeType": "video/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.640020\"",
                "bitrate": 316170,
                "width": 1080,
                "height": 1080,
                "initRange": {
                    "start": "0",
                    "end": "742"
                },
                "indexRange": {
                    "start": "743",
                    "end": "1098"
                },
                "lastModified": "1626285318503749",
                "contentLength": "5218436",
                "quality": "hd1080",
                "fps": 25,
                "qualityLabel": "1080p",
                "projectionType": "RECTANGULAR",
                "averageBitrate": 302518,
                "approxDurationMs": "138000",
                "signatureCipher": "s=llOq0QJ8wRgIhALBndRNo-IlMQBQxtR_6VN8m3fdKkle1RnuAY8kT2AAKAiEr2OtVnsJ21TH%3DhVP3qe_56J9Blho-4wC90jybqw_4Aic%3DicA&sp=sig&url=https://rr7---sn-hv8pnu5gjv-c59l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback%3Fexpire%3D1682160014%26ei%3DLmVDZO6nIYyUkAPnoK-gCQ%26ip%3Daqui suele ir la ip%26id%3Do-AOh_076MrqB5N4lKPl8m3txXwP3wasdpOU2V32UBzwlC%26itag%3D137%26source%3Dyoutube%26requiressl%3Dyes%26mh%3DlI%26mm%3D31%252C29%26mn%3Dsn-hv8pnu5gjv-c59l%252Csn-hp57yn7r%26ms%3Dau%252Crdu%26mv%3Dm%26mvi%3D7%26pl%3D19%26gcr%3Dco%26initcwndbps%3D1013750%26spc%3D99c5CXYcGOJfeIHTtDTjmwN5dzKF6Jc%26vprv%3D1%26mime%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%26ns%3DINJof8EulkDyqymfDEjVreYM%26gir%3Dyes%26clen%3D5218436%26dur%3D138.000%26lmt%3D1626285318503749%26mt%3D1682137990%26fvip%3D5%26keepalive%3Dyes%26fexp%3D24007246%26c%3DWEB_REMIX%26txp%3D2316224%26n%3D2e2si1papKXU1vD_z%26sparams%3Dexpire%252Cei%252Cip%252Cid%252Citag%252Csource%252Crequiressl%252Cgcr%252Cspc%252Cvprv%252Cmime%252Cns%252Cgir%252Cclen%252Cdur%252Clmt%26lsparams%3Dmh%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cmvi%252Cpl%252Cinitcwndbps%26lsig%3DAG3C_xAwRgIhANU7NhCEUvPI3WsKImCKwXadQ0042aSow7EtVipIsCVYAiEA-BfiVxY-9RO4RNkJmV1xVMXRdT6mf4Fvy4T6kseZQEE%253D"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada quiero señalar es importante tener en cuenta que esto puede violar los términos de servicio de YouTube.

Encontre una libreria  que ayuda a solucionar tu problema ("Recuerdo que el problema consiste en cómo obtener la URL valida para poder solicitar la canción").
"github.com/kkdai/youtube/v2" necesita tener la version de go actualizada go1.21.1
Aqui el codigo:

```
import (
"fmt"
"github.com/kkdai/youtube/v2"
"io"
"log"
"net/http"
"os"
)

func main() {
client := &youtube.Client{}

// some free video - no copyright de YouTube
videoID := "https://youtu.be/CYDP_8UTAus?si=2WyeXc4BGN1-ExmD"
video, err := client.GetVideo(videoID)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Busca la mejor calidad de stream de audio y obtén la URL
var audioURL string
for _, v := range video.Formats {
    if v.AudioQuality != "" {
        audioURL = v.URL
        break
    }
}

fmt.Println("Audio URL:", audioURL)
}
```